# Where should I catch a Perl 6 warning control exception?

Tags: exception, warnings, raku

I'm playing around with Perl 6's control exceptions. A [warn](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/warn) raises a control exception which is invisible to normal exception control flow, and that exception resumes itself. That's kinda cool.

So, playing around with this, I wrote this to see what would happen. I'm not trying to solve a particular problem other than seeing what Perl 6 actually does:

```
use v6;

try {
    CONTROL {
        put "Caught an exception, in the try";
        put .^name;
        }
    do-that-thing-you-do();
    }

sub do-that-thing-you-do {
    CONTROL {
        put "Caught an exception, in the sub";
        put .^name;
        }
    warn "This is a warning";
    }
```

It looks like both fire:

```
Caught an exception, in the sub
CX::Warn
Caught an exception, in the try
CX::Warn
This is a warning
  in sub do-that-thing-you-do at resume.p6 line 16
MoarVM panic: Trying to unwind over wrong handler
```

Notice there's a Moar panic, which [I've raise an issue for](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/issues/572). But, I'm not really asking about that.

I'm curious about the picture of the flow here. I expected that a `CONTROL` in the sub would catch the exception and resume, so it wouldn't percolate up to the `try`. How should that flow?

Also, notice the exception is `CX::Warn`. I don't think I've done something odd there, but the [Perl 6 types](https://docs.perl6.org/type.html) don't even list `X::Warn`

Comment: note that the whole `CX::` namespace is not documented on that page...

Comment: Please add an Issue to https://github.com/perl6/doc for missing documentation.  Thank you!

Comment: Doc issue: https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1268

Answer (score 6):

To get the same behavior as the default warnings handler, then it's necessary to both catch the exception (as with `CATCH`, a `CONTROL` without smart-matching will re-throw) and also to `resume` after it.

```
CONTROL {
    when CX::Warn {
        say "Warning: $_";
        .resume
    }
}

sub foo() {
    say 1;
    warn 'oh gosh...';
    say 2;               # Not reached without .resume
}
foo();
```

There are many other control exceptions, and so it is wise to only match on `CX::Warn` rather than use `default`. Otherwise, `take`, `next`, `last`, `emit`, `done` (and, in 6.d, probably also `await`) could be netted by your handler, which would surely make for quite some headaches.